# Open input when start the page

Tags: javascript, html

How to open this input file when opening the page? This way when I select it already does the submit, but how to make it open when starting the page?

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Basic Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function submeter(){
            document.formulario.submit();
        }

    </script>

    <form method="POST" action="#" name="formulario" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input id="up" type="file" onchange="submeter()" name="fileUpload" accept="image/*">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside of user-initiated events (such as click events, see: [Event.isTrusted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted)) you cannot programmatically open a file input. Therefore, you cannot open it on page load.

There is no workaround.

Comment: Can I simulate a click?

Comment: @WotonSampaio "There is no workaround" simulating a click would be a workaround, no?

Comment: You can try, but modern browsers won't open a file input on a non-user-initiated event. A simulated click wouldn't be user-initiated.

Comment: @Isaac No need to hit :/